# Why does string interpolation not work in this case?

Tags: scala

What's wrong with the following interpolated string? Compiler complains that symbol `str` cannot be found:

```
private def colorGreen(str: String) = s"\u001B[32m$str\u001B[0m" // does not work
private def colorGreen(str: String) = s"\u001B[32m${str}\u001B[0m" // works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the Scala string interpolator automatically appends the unicode in `s"\u001B[32m$str\u001B[0m"` (even though it means `<ESC>`). Therefore it looks for a variable named `str\u001B`.

In principal you could have the following interpolation working:

```
private def colorGreen(str\u001B: String) = s"\u001B[32m$str\u001B[0m"
```

Comment: That has to be a bug, right?  The clue is that your backticks are not necessary.  It's because `Character.isIdentifierIgnorable` are not ignored. The spec doesn't say you can embed zeroes in a "plain id".  But what do I know.

Comment: Right, we don’t need the backticks for it to be parsed as an identifier. But then it’s rather consistent with the string interpolation behaviour, isn’t it?

Comment: There are old java bugs to clarify this behavior (that ignorables are not ignored). I'm not sure the Scala spec covers it precisely or clearly, but the clarification is, whatever isUnicodeIdentifierPart says.